# Print the object as string

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

I have convert the json  response into string to append with pdf. `summary_data` is the response I want to convert as string and append into pdf.

```js
const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},
    {Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9}, 
     {Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];
    
       var str="";
     $.each(summary_data, function (key, entry) {
              str=str.entry."<br>";
            });
             console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use JSON method stringify()

```
       constsummary_data=[
        {
          Geo: "US West",
          MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized",
          count: 65
        },
        {
          Geo: "NSU",
          MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized",
          count: 9
        },
        {
          Geo: "US East",
          MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized",
          count: 3
       }
     ];
     console.log(JSON.stringify(summary_data));
```

your JSON will be converted into a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `JSON.stringify`

try this code:

```js
const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},{Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9}, {Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];

var str = JSON.stringify(summary_data)
       
console.log(str)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify`

```js
const summary_data=[{Geo: "US West", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 65},
{Geo: "NSU", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 9},{Geo: "US East", MeetingHash: "Hold/Uncategorized", count: 3}];

// prints as string
console.log(JSON.stringify(summary_data));

// prints as formatted string
console.log(JSON.stringify(summary_data, null, 4));

// prints as <br> concatenated string
var str = "";
$.each(summary_data, function(key, entry) {
  str += JSON.stringify(entry) + "<br>";
});
console.log(str);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```